# WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD

Tags: php

I Cannot login.When click button login its show WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD.The db is id,username,password and level.  SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `level` FROM `login`

```
<?php
ob_start();
$message = "";
if ( isset ($_POST['login']))
  {
   include 'admin/dbconnect.php';
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   if ($username != "" && $password != "")
   {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) ;
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) ==1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['isLogged_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
        $message = 'Logged-in successfully';
        }
        else
        {
            $message = 'WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $message = 'PLEASE RE-INPUT YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD';
    }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Please post the URL to your website so we can not visit it for storing our passwords in the clear.

Comment: Also so we can totally not take it down via an SQL INJECTION!

Comment: did you check error log?

Comment: check how many rows are coming might be more than 1.

Comment: did u ever check your db connection if its right?

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_escape_string to protect against sql injections, also if you have php 5.5.0 or better you should be using something like mysqli because all the mysql_ commands are deprecated.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '%s' and password = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($username), mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

As for the actual problem, it may be as other people have said (db connection) and just to be safe just say: (for multiple entries if thats even possible)

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result))
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you try it using:

```
SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password' LIMIT 1
```

`LIMIT 1` at the end.

Maybe you have multiple rows matching the same username and password.

Comment: i have only 1 row data. i try put LIMIT 1 but not working

Comment: -1 question is not an answer.